# How to use an EC2 ip address in a Security Group inside cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am a bit new to cloudformation and I have trouble to parameter, or find information, about how to reference an ec2 IP adress in my security group.
The two are defined in my stack and my SG depends on the EC2. Here is my SG:

```
        "3DEXPPLAT": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "3DPLAT SG",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "CidrIp": {"Ref" : "CFAPA"}
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "STACK_3DEXPSG"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "59898995-0f8d-4cbe-b315-c9c68df319b2"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "CFAPA"
        ]
    }
```

So, what should i put in my CidrIp in the SecurityGroupIngress to make my SG use the private IP of my EC2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Fn::Ref` on an EC2 Instance, you are retrieving its Instance Id. For your security group, you need the IP (using `Fn::GetAtt`), and you need to format it as a CIDR block (adding the notation with the `Fn::Sub`). So, assuming `CFAPA` is your EC2 Instance, this should work:

```javascript
{
    "3DEXPPLAT": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "3DPLAT SG",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "CidrIp": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${CFAPA.PrivateIp}/32"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- you don't need to specify the `DependsOn` attribute, since CloudFormation will figure out the dependency because of the reference. This simplifies the code.
- to figure out the property to use on `Fn::GetAtt` was called `PrivateIp`, you have to refer to the "Return Values" section of the [AWS::EC2::Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-returnvalues) documentation. This is where you notice that `Fn::Ref` returns Instance Id.
- keep in mind that Private IPs might change. So you might want to attach the `CFAPA` to another Security Group and create the permissions based on the security groups membership. This is an architecture decision though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now that you explained it it makes perfect sense to me :)

Comment: @Andrea I always forget you don't need the full `Fn::Sub` mapping if using only template values. Take another look at this should simplify things a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

This is the wrong approach.

Rather than reference explicit IP addresses of internal nodes, you should specify another security group as the source ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules)). One common approach is to define a security group for each application, and attach those groups to the ELB, EC2, and RDS instance(s) that make up that application.

You can attach up to 5 security groups to a network interface, so this "internal communication" group can be in addition to any "external communication" group(s) that you might use (for example, a rule on the ELB that accepts traffic from the Internet).

One caveat for CloudFormation: you won't be able to define your ingress rules inline. Instead, you'll need a separate [ingress rule definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html) that references the already-defined security group.

Comment: I don't think you should call it a "wrong approach". The question is on how to reference Private IPs within CloudFormation, and we don't have enough information to understand the architecture that is planned. I agree that management through SGs is preferred, but we should not judge without having the whole picture.

Comment: @tyron - if I were to see someone trying to run across a busy highway, I would tell that person it was a bad idea. Ditto when I see someone writing a brittle configuration template.